# Can find the php.ini file

Tags: apache2, php

I've installed PHP 5.2.17 on Apache 2 on Windows Vista into the directory c:\Web\Webserver\PHP5\

However phpinfo in showing that the Configuration File Path is c:\Windows and the Loaded Configuration File is (none).

The httpd.conf has the following lines:

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/Web/WebServer/PHP5/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir 'c:\Web\Webserver\PHP5\'
```

Windows control panel shows that the path environment variable includes my installation directory (at the front of the path) and that PHPRC variable also points to my installation directory.

So why is it looking in c:\Windows for the php.ini?

If I put a copy of php.ini in c:\Windows it still says that it cannot find it. What's going on?

Comment: Try using backslashes instead of forward slashes for the LoadModule directive.

Comment: Modern versions of Windows (since 7, at least) can handle front slashes; furthermore, I think Apache wants front slashes ... which **may** be a clue about the PHPIniDir line.

Comment: @PTBNL: Then the phpinidir should be front slashes as well.

Comment: The LoadModule obviously works with forward slashes as the PHP module has been loaded. Otherwise I wouldn't get anything out of the phpinfo() function.

Changing PHPIniDir to forward slashes causes Apache to throw an error when restarting (and then failing to start)

Answer (score 1):

try to search php.ini from search in windows

Comment: Nothing found in c:\Windows or it sub-directories.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `PHPRC` is a *system* variable, and not a *user* variable?

Have you rebooted?

Have you installed Sysinternals Process Explorer, and right-clicked the Apache process to verify that the `PHPRC` parameter is in the enviroment (via the Properties tab).

Have you considered Linux? :)

Comment: PHPRC is defined as a system variable. I have rebooted. I have used Sysinternals Process Explorer, but the Environment shows no entries for any variable.

Linux is not an option (no spare machine and my Linux SysAdmin skills are worse than my Windows SysAdmin skills)

Answer (score -1):

The above answers are good, but didn't solve the problem that we had.

As the others mentioned (spot on), I created a file:

```
<?php
phpinfo(); 
?>
```

So that worked great. However, it showed "(none)"

So where do you find (none)!?

You can't find what doesn't exist, of course.

The answer actually is, you don't HAVE a php.ini; you'll need to create it.

In my case, on Windows, you just go to where php is installed; I had already had installed it in `c:\php` I believe it would be the same steps on other platforms.

Then, from a command line, powershell for ex, type:  `notepad c:\php\php.ini`

Tell it yes, you do want to create it, then add whatever changes you needed in the first place. For me, for example:

```
extension_dir = "c:\php\ext"
extension=mysqli
upload_max_filesize = 25M
post_max_size = 13M
max_execution_time = 300
```

Then save. Fixed!

By the way - if you do "file new" and then "save as" Notepad will (not so) helpfully rename your file to php.ini.txt.